# Anyone know an example algorithm for word segmentation using dynamic programming?

Tags: dynamic, cpu-word, iteration, text-segmentation

If you search google for word segmentation there really are no very good descriptions of it and I'm just trying to fully understand the process a dynamic programming algorithm takes to find a segmentation of a string into individual words.  Does anyone know a place where there is a good description of a word segmentation problem or can anyone describe it?

Word Segmentation is basically just taking a string of characters and deciding where to split it up into words if you didn't know and using dynamic programming it would take into account some amount of subproblems.  This is pretty simple to do using recursion but I haven't been able to find anywhere online to find even just a description of an iterative algorithm for this online, so if anyone has any examples or can give an algorithm that would be great.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why does this have to be harder than just splitting the string at every space character?

Comment: See my answer for an example, d.

Comment: Yea the spaces are removed for the string of characters.  Dav, what would you do if you had a list of words that were valid so you also had to check if a word was valid or not?  I'm having a hard time understanding your implementation exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that we're not talking about the trivial case here (i.e. not just splitting a string around spaces, since that'd just be a basic tokenizer problem) - but instead, we're talking about something were there isn't a clear word delimiter character, and thus we're having to "guess" what the best match for string->words would be - for instance, the case of a set of concatenated words w/o spaces, such as transforming this:

```
lotsofwordstogether
```

into this:

```
lots, of, words, together
```

In this case, the dynamic programming approach would probably be to calculate out a table where one dimension corresponds to the `M`th word in the sequence, and the other dimension corresponds to each `N`th character in the input string. Then the value that you fill in for each square of the table is "the best match score we can get if we end (or instead, begin) the `M`th word at position `N`.

Answer (score 2):

The [Python wordsegment module](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/) has such an algorithm. It uses recursion and memoization to implement dynamic programming.

The source is available on [Github](https://github.com/grantjenks/wordsegment/blob/master/wordsegment.py), here's the relevant snippet:

```
def segment(text):
    "Return a list of words that is the best segmenation of `text`."

    memo = dict()

    def search(text, prev='<s>'):
        if text == '':
            return 0.0, []

        def candidates():
            for prefix, suffix in divide(text):
                prefix_score = log10(score(prefix, prev))

                pair = (suffix, prefix)
                if pair not in memo:
                    memo[pair] = search(suffix, prefix)
                suffix_score, suffix_words = memo[pair]

                yield (prefix_score + suffix_score, [prefix] + suffix_words)

        return max(candidates())

    result_score, result_words = search(clean(text))

    return result_words
```

Note how `memo` caches calls to `search` which in turn selects the max from `candidates`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the followings solution in iterative style (The main idea is breaking up problem into: finding segmentation having exactly 1,2,3..n segmented words within a certain range of the input. Excuse me if there are any minor indexing mistakes, my head is very fuzzy these days. But this is an iterative solution for you.):

```
static List<String> connectIter(List<String> tokens) {

    // use instead of array, the key is of the from 'int int'
    Map<String, List<String>> data = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    int n = tokens.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String str = concat(tokens, i, n);
        if (dictContains(str)) {
            data.put(1 + " " + i, Collections.singletonList(str));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int start = 0; i < n; start++) {
            List<String> solutions = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int end = start + 1; end <= n - i + 1; end++) {
                String firstPart = concat(tokens, start, end);

                if (dictContains(firstPart)) {
                    List<String> partialSolutions = data.get((i - 1) + " " + end);
                    if (partialSolutions != null) {
                        List<String> newSolutions = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (String onePartialSolution : partialSolutions) {
                            newSolutions.add(firstPart + " "
                                    + onePartialSolution);
                        }
                        solutions.addAll(newSolutions);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (solutions.size() != 0) {
                data.put(i + " " + start, solutions);
            }
        }
    }

    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // can be optimized to run with less iterations
        List<String> solutions = data.get(i + " " + 0);
        if (solutions != null) {
            ret.addAll(solutions);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


static private String concat(List<String> tokens, int low, int hi) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = low; i < hi; i++) {
        sb.append(tokens.get(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Feel free to correct indexing if I made mistakes here